# Prolog: Unification of Arithmetic Expression and Constant

Tags: prolog, unification

I am trying to learn Prolog for an exam.

According to my slides arithmetic expressions do not unify with constants. 
Is there a reason for?

for example

```
 even(0).
 even(X) :- X>0, odd(X-1).

 odd(1).
 odd(X) :- X>1, even(X-1).  

    ?-even(2).
 => false.
```

The `0` doesn't unify with `(X-1)`.

So my Question is: Would it be a problem in some case if there was unification between constants and arithmetic expressions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with those clauses is that Prolog doesn't evaluate arithmetic expressions inline as arguments to queries to predicates.

So this:

```
even(X) :- X>0, odd(X-1).
odd(X) :- X>1, even(X-1).
```

If queried as `even(2)` will result in:

```
2 > 0,   % success
odd(2-1). % hmmm
```

Then `odd(2-1)` (which really means `odd('-'(2,1))`) won't match `odd(1)`, it will go to `odd(X)` and give:

```
2-1>1,  % This will evaluate, but will fail because 1>1 is false
```

Since `>/2` is an evaluating comparison, it does the evaluation. But it's too late for that, since the wrong clause has been selected. So you get failure.

You need to pre-evaluate:

```
even(0).
even(X) :- X>0, X1 is X-1, odd(X1).

odd(1).
odd(X) :- X>1, X1 is X-1, even(X1).
```

Prolog will evaluate expressions that are on the second argument of `is/2`, such as:

```
Y is (X+1)/2.
```

Or if in comparison operators that compare numerically. For example, the following will evaluate the expressions before comparison:

```
Y+7 < X*2
X/2 =:= Y mod 2
```

Note that `=/2` does not evaluate expressions. It is a *unification* operator. So:

```
X-2 = Y*2
```

Would fail because it attempts to unify `'-'(X,2)` with `'*'(Y,2)`.

Comment: Thanks, if I understand correctly there is only Prolog problem when I try to unify Y+2 = CONST, not a logical, isn't it? I have to tell Prolog with "special" operators like "is", that it should evaluate the expression first.

Comment: @nomiko in that case you're using unification (`=/2`), so it won't evaluate `Y+2`. If `Y` has a value and you do `Y + 2 =:= CONST` then Prolog will evaluate `Y+2` and, if `CONST` is a numeric constant, not a variable, will properly compare them.